# How to access Struct framework ( JSP ) form variable for Ajax query

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, struct

Please help. I have implemented registration form of my website using struct framework for VALIDATION.

```
  <html:form action="servletregister.do" method="post" style="width: 95%">
  <tr>
       <td>User ID : * </td>
       <td><html:text property="userid" /> <html:errors property="userid"/></td>

       td> <html:button property="button" value="check Availability" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #11bdd1; width: 130px;" onclick="test();" />

         <div id="AJAX"> // where ajax query result will show

         </div>
  </tr>
```

Problem is, that i want to validate **USERID** using AJAX .

```
 function test(){
            var userId = document.getElementById("userid").value;
            if(userId=="")
                {
                      alert("Please Enter UserID");
                }
             else {



                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        var content = document.getElementById("AJAX");
                        content.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                    //xmlhttp.open("get","table.jsp?num="+num,true);
                    //xmlhttp.send(null);

                    xmlhttp.open("post","validate.jsp",true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.send("userId="+userId);
             }
        }
```

IF i **dont** use Structs , IT IS VERY EASY TO ACCESS USER ID DOM OBJECT. But i am unable to figure out how to access struct USER ID TEXTField in Javascript. Please Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In struts `styleId` Attribute renders an "id" attribute.So change your code as shown below

```
<html:text property="userid" styleId="userid" />
```

Reference:http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/text.html